# Spring boot+ Spring SAML not working for NGINX proxy_pass

Tags: spring-boot, spring-saml

I have structure where my rest service (SP) are build using spring boot + Spring SAML for authentication and UI using Nginx as reverse proxy.
If calling service by return/rewrite with direct URL everything is working fine : Calling IDP getting authenticated and return response.
But if I call same service using proxy_pass it fails with InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message

I have structure where UI using NGINX as web server and through NGINX calling SP.
SP having multiple instances under LB. Used SAMLContextProviderLB as context provider.

How can I do this calling using Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your Nginx isn't configured to use sticky sessions. This causes that response from IDP can land on a server which isn't aware of the request which was originally sent from the other server, and therefore fail validating it. The Spring SAML manual says:

> Make sure that your reverse-proxy or load-balancer is configured to
>   use sticky sessions.

There are multiple possible solutions:

- enable sticky sessions on the Nginx, so the response goes to the same server which sent it
- disable validations of InResponseTo fields (see [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html) for details)
- enable HTTP session replication, so the HttpSession which contains the sent request is distributed to all servers - for doing this see e.g. [spring-session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-enablehazelcasthttpsession)

Comment: Thanks Vladi. Your response always help. I posted my next set of question with respect to your suggestion. Please suggest for those.